# opengl texture filtering low quality

Tags: windows, opengl, textures

On my windows machine I see no difference between next settings:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

and

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

and both are of quite bad quality. Am I missing some settings in pipeline?

And if this is some kind of oddity what are my options to overcome this by the means of 
opengl without using custom scaling?

Don't sure about `windows` tag. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For minifictation, you likely want to enable mipmapping. See GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, otherwise you will get very noticeable aliasing in high frequency textures, when you zoom in more than 2x.
Of course, you need to generate mipmaps, do use this!

Answer (score 1):

The filter is applicable only when a texture in minified respect the original size.

What is your projection parameters, and how do you display the texture? Answering to these question may help us to find the solution.

Probably your texture is not minified, I suppose. In this case, try to setup the MAG_FILTER texture parameter to have effects using your projection.