# Why do OpenGL resized images look pixelated?

Tags: opengl, rust

I want to display 2 textures on 2 squares. Here's what it looks like.
[image]

left side 325x325 ( the same size as the image ), right side (100x100)

the image size is 325x325. How to make the texture of the right side more sharp.
the only way to get good quality is when I use textures and objects with the same size.
I'm using PNG images and the following GL methods.

```
gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);
gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);
```

My vertex

```c
#version 430 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout(location = 2) in float layer;
out vec2 uv;
out float layer_get;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    uv = texCoord;
    layer_get = layer;
}
```

My fragment

```c
#version 430 core
out vec4 color;

in vec2 uv;
in float layer_get;

layout (binding=0) uniform sampler2DArray textureArray;

void main()
{
   color = texture(textureArray, vec3(uv.x,uv.y, 0));
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opengl texture filtering low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261089/opengl-texture-filtering-low-quality)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/hdcpk8/why_do_opengl_resized_images_look_pixelated/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and the linked question, you can improve the quality by [trilinear filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_filtering) and generating [Mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap).

Use one of the "mipmap" texture minifying functions `gl::NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `gl::LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `gl::NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` or `gl::LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`:

```
gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl::LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR as i32);
```

Generate the mip maps by [`gl::GenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) after specifying the two-dimensional texture image (after `gl::TexImage2D`):

```
gl::GenerateMipmap(gl::TEXTURE_2D)
```